# How to find more information about a registered case in Berlin, Germany?

Tags: germany

One of my friends registered a case against someone, and now we are looking for how to find more information via the case number/ID online?

The case number looks like this: 520***-00**-439***

Of course, one way is to go to the police station and find more information there, but we have heard that we can also do it online.

Answer (score 1):

> One of my friends registered a case against someone, and now we are looking for how to find more information via the case number/ID online?
> ..., but we have heard that we can also do it online.

What you have heard of is probably the [Internetwache](https://www.bussgeldkatalog.org/internetwache-berlin/), but that is for making/reporting of charges and **not** the viewing of existing cases (of possibly other peaple).

> **Wann nutze ich die Berliner Internetwache?**
> Die Internetwache Berlin soll **die Erstattung von Anzeigen erleichtern** und dient als ergänzendes Angebot. In Notsituation ist die Polizei allerdings weiterhin über den Notruf 110 zu verständigen.
>
> > **When can I use the Berlin internet station?**
> > The Internet Policestation Berlin **aims to facilitate the making of charges** and serves as a complementary offer. In emergency situations the police are, however, should be contacted at the 110 emergency number.

With the case number, you probably also have a contact address/person who is responsible for the case.

They would probably first check, depending on the situation, on what informieren can be given.

---

**Sources**:

- [Internetwache für Berlin: Wie wird Bürgern weitergeholfen?](https://www.bussgeldkatalog.org/internetwache-berlin/)

  - see bottom of page for links to other states